# Delay when updating the background of a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, delay, setbackground

I'm using setBackgroundImage:forState: to update the background of a UIButton. The background is updated but only after a few seconds. There is obviously some refresh cycle at work here but I can't find exactly what the problem is. I've tried to play with setNeedsRefresh and setNeedsDisplay without any result.

How can I change the UIButton background instantaneously ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the image stored? Locally or remotely?

Comment: Post some code where we can know exact problem.

Comment: Are you setting color at the time of initialization of button or later sometime?

Comment: Image is stored locally and i'm not setting anything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange delays like this are usually caused when you try and perform UIKit operations on a background thread (e.g. in a delegate callback). Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // set your button background here
});
```

Comment: This exact same code did not solve my problem but put me in the right direction. This is probably a threading related problem.

Comment: mmm after some tests it appears that setBackgroundImage is called in main thread already :-(

Comment: Well that's very strange then. Setting the background image should be immediate. Is the image particularly large?

Comment: My mistake. This is indeed a thread problem and your solution works. It's just that I have synchronous and asynchronous image loading in my app and did not check the right part of the code. Thanks !